# how to get read continuous flow of data from a tcp server using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcp

I am working on a winform application which will plot a graph from the data it is getting from a device that is connected to it through ethernet and using tcp. The device sends 12byte packets in which 1st 5 bytes contain metadata and last 8 bytes is the actual data I want to plot.
How can I start reading data using a button press until I tell the application to stop reading anymore?

Currently on a button press the application connects to the tcp server through tcp.conncet method and the I read data using Networkstream.Read method and storing it.
But I am not sure if it reads continuously or it just read once when the button is pressed and so I have to use loop or not.

Comment: The read method reads what is currently in the receive buffer.  When sending continuously the first byte of data may be in the middle of the message so you need to initially align the receive data and may need to throw away a partial message.  Once aligned you have to check if your buffer has at least 12 bytes of data and then remove 12 bytes at a time.

Comment: how can I check for which byte is the first byte in the message? and does using **networkStream.read**  reads the whole buffer?

Comment: It depends on the data.  Some data has started character.  Other has end character

Comment: Yeah but the data packets my device sends don't have a start bit or end bit. But as I checked during reading it always gives me full packets so that is not a problem. But my question is how can I read continuously? does networkstream.Read method do that if I don't close the network stream?

Comment: There is probably a return at end of each message.  Do not depend on data coming in one junk if you want your code robust.  Devices usually have a continuous mode that you may need to set either manually or by command.  If device does not have continuous mode than after you receive each chunk you have to send a message.

Comment: the device sends data continuously. The problem is how do I read the data continuously? or where can I read about it

Comment: I usually use a list (temporary buffer) and put receive data into a buffer.  You may get more than one message in each chunk.  Also use a Event for the receive data so you do not need to loop.

Comment: See following : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/cs4ch23.aspx?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

there is a parameter indicating weather data is available in the stream or not, so you can do something like

```
while(NetworkStream.DataAvailable)
{
   //read data
}
```

but it will break when you will receive all the data from the stream after that you can check from time to time if there is some more data available in the stream and start reading it

```
while (true)
{
    while (NetworkStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        //read data
    }

    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```